# Cast to xbox one

Tags: video-streaming

Windows 10 just updated itself yet again (after me turning auto updates off, just keeps resetting it!), so I fdisk'd it and have gone back to Linux.  It's still lush!

One thing I am going to miss is the right click on a video file and select "cast to xbox".  Is there some tool/extension or something I can use to do something similar in ubuntu?

I'd like to avoid messing about with DNLA server, especially the likes of plex...

Thanks in advance

Jim

Comment: http://mediatomb.cc/  http://askubuntu.com/questions/277862/how-do-i-properly-install-and-configure-mediatomb